# Outlying pixels in OpenCV warpPerspective()

Tags: opencv

My application requires mapping one quadrilateral to another quadrilateral. Neither of these are rectangles.

However, the result I get from warpPerspective() is always a rectangle. I have tried setting the "outlier" flag to different values to prevent pixels from outside the warped quad from appearing in the destination image but nothing seems to work. What I want is a warped quad with the pixels outside the warped quad set to transparency.

How do I achieve this?

Alternatively, is there a straightforward way to mask the region outside a quadrilateral in OpenCV so that I can copy just the quad to another image?

In case it is relevant, I am using the Python binding to OpenCV.

Here is my current code:

```
def warpImage(image, corners, target, width, height):
    mat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(corners, target)
    out = numpy.zeros(shape=(width, height), dtype="uint8")
    out = cv2.warpPerspective(image, mat, (width,height), out, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return out
```

corners and target are both non-rectangular quads. The output is a full widthxheight rectangle, however. None of the pixels are black or transparent. Instead they are pixels from the image both inside and outside the corners quad. I only want the ones inside.

Comment: Can you please provide an image of your currently warped quad to better illustrate your problem?

Comment: I'm a little unclear how this would help. The result is a rectangle with all pixels visible. I want a nonrectangular quad with the bits outside transparent. I provided nonrectangular quads as input.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you should provide a code sample of what you are doing. Because warpPerspective should indeed output a quad with pixels outside the quad painted black.

Comment: OK, I have done so. The behaviour you describe would be just as good as transparent. But I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I have found is to cycle through the pixels and copy the ones in the warped quad to a remap array using the matplotlib pnpoly() function, as so:

```
import matplotlib.nxutils as nx 

def warpImage(image, corners, target, width, height, x0, y0, remap):
    mat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(corners, target)
    out = cv2.warpPerspective(image, mat, (width,height), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    for x in range(0,width):
        for y in range(0,height):
            if nx.pnpoly(x,y,target) == 1:
                for i in range(0,3):
                    remap[y+y0,x+x0,i] = out[y,x,i]

    return remap
```

I loop through all the quads in image and accumulate transformed versions in remap.

Having to access each pixel is not very efficient but fortunately this is a one time transformation.